# add event to class jquery where not has event?

Tags: jquery

i add element to page after the page is loaded
and I want to add event of class element 
where the event not exist

like this

```
$('.className').map(function () {
    if ($._data($(this), "events").length == 0)
        return $(this)
}).get().click(function () {
    alert();
})
```

because I don't want that to append a lot of times

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want but, if you want to bind an element to an event only once, you should use the `.one()` method of jquery

Comment: Maybe edit my question or something else
Because my English is poor forgiveness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below snippet remove get() it'll not return you an elements secondly 
`$._data($(this)[0], "events")` it will not return you an array so remove `length` just check with `undefined`

```js
$('.className').map(function () {
  debugger;
    if ($._data($(this)[0], "events") == undefined)
        return $(this)[0]
}).click(function () {
    alert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="className" >1</a>
```